# How can I load dates prior to 1900 and view them in power bi desktop and report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Am loading a set of data in power bi for data quality reporting. my data is in SQL server. my data looks like below. this loads without any issues into power bi.
[source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4yoK.png)

but after loading it, power bi does not present the dates that are earlier than 1900, so this is what appears
[power bi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dbuq.png)

I would like all date values to appear even those before 1900 so that we can correct the data.

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help
Richard

Comment: This is happening because the underlying tabular storage used by Power BI doesn't support such dates, but only those after 0100-01-01 -- this is a legacy of the old automation date/time format. Values before 1900 are still supported, just not those before 100. Several workarounds suggest themselves; I think the least hassle here would be to change the import to convert the dates to text (in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format) since comparisons are then still easy. Of course you could also have two columns, one holding it as a date for supported values, one as text.

Comment: All in all I don't think I would suggest PBI as the tool of choice for data quality analysis, precisely because its types are not specialized to hold the broadest possible ranges of values. If you go that route you probably want to be conservative and import *everything* as text to begin with, converting it only when necessary for specific checks that couldn't be done otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, the conversion to text solved the problem